# Pattern to convert different types of similar unchangeable objects to the same object

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have an existing system that inserts books into a library database, and I want to generalize it to include other media.

The other media is similar, but not exactly the same, and all media are third party dependencies/models that I cannot change myself. (Otherwise I would have them all implement a single interface). Is it possible to do an Adapter, Converter, or Bridge pattern here?

```
public class libraryDAO {

    private DatabaseConnection db;
    
    public libraryDAO () {
       this.db = DatabaseConnection.getNewConnection(); 
    }

    public insertIntoDB (Book book) {
        this.db.insert(book.toMap());
    }

}

public class Book {
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String coverArtId;
    public Integer pages;
}
```

Now I have more media types this system needs to support (and imagine 10 others)

```
public class Film {
    public String title;
    public String director;
    public Integer runtimeInMinutes;
}

public class Lyrics {
    public String song;
    public String lyricist;
}
```

So I naively created a huge class that can convert any of these media types:

```
public class Media {
    public String title;
    public String creator;
    public Integer runtimeInMinutes;
    public Integer pages; 

    public Media (Book book) {
        this.title            = book.title;
        this.creator          = book.author;
        this.coverArtId       = book.coverArtId;
        this.runtimeInMinutes = 0;
        this.pages            = book.pages;
    }

    public Media (Film film) {
        this.title            = film.title;
        this.creator          = film.director;
        this.coverArtId       = 0;
        this.runtimeInMinutes = film.runtimeInMinutes;
        this.pages            = 0;
    }

    public Media (Lyrics lyrics) {
        this.title            = lyrics.song;
        this.creator          = lyrics.lyricist;
        this.coverArtId       = 0;
        this.runtimeInMinutes = 0;
        this.pages            = 1;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        //code that maps all the fields to a Map for DB insertion
    }
}
```

And then update my libraryDAO like so:

```
public class libraryDAO {

    private DatabaseConnection db;
    
    public libraryDAO () {
       this.db = DatabaseConnection.getNewConnection(); 
    }

    public insertIntoDB (Media media) {
        this.db.insert(media.toMap());
    }

}
```

But this doesn't scale, right? And it must be incorrect to have a giant class that just converts a wide-range of objects into a DB-acceptable state?

Is there a pattern that I'm missing? I can't use interfaces since I don't control the media types Book, Film, Lyrics, so I don't think I can use the Adapter, Converter, Bridge patterns.

Comment: From your question, it is not clear **why** you need to convert those library items to objects of a single class `Media`. Why don't you persist each library item in an individual database table, one which reflects the individual structure of each item type?

Comment: serialise to json/xml and save to a "data" column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recursively serialize an object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623091/how-to-recursively-serialize-an-object-using-reflection)

Comment: `Is there a pattern that I'm missing? ` What's wrong with the never old fashioned `data mapper`? Basically, it's what you are doing right now in `Media`. So,  it just takes you to create the right abstraction and move all that code into concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What's wrong with your current design?

The design of the `Media` class breaks the [Open / Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), that says a class should be open for extension and closed for modification:  every time you want to add a new kind of media you have to modify your class with the risk of breaking something.

Moreover, having the `Media` conversion (e.g. constructing a `Media` from a `Book`) requires to expose the properties as public.  This is not in line with sound [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) principles.

#### How to improve it?

There are several alternative designs that you could consider:

- refactor the `Book`, `Film` and `Lyrics` class to make them inherit from a class that provides for the common denominator. But the problem is that properties like `page` are not really a common denominator.
- let `Book`, `Film` and `Lyrics` class implement an interface `MediaConvertible`, that ensures that the object can be converted into a `Media`.
- get rid of the intermediary `Media` and let `Book`, `Film` and `Lyrics` class implement an interface `MediaMappable` that implements a method `toMap()`.

#### Digging further

This last approach would allow to generalise your DAO and isolate DAO specifics from the rest:

```
public interface MediaMappable {
    public Map<String, Object> toMap();
}

public class libraryDAO {
    ...
    public insertIntoDB (MediaMappable media) {
        this.db.insert(media.toMap());
    }    
}
```

You then can change your different classes to provide directly a relevant media mapping:

```
public class Book : MediaMappable {
    ...
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        // code to get a map with all media relevant fields
    }
}
```

The advantage is that it's simple to add new media, and can work with all the class properties being private.  By the way,  the map plays a similar role than a [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), with the difference being that its internal state is shared between a sender (the media object) and a receiver (the DAO).